# autocomplete text view and select an item of string

Tags: java, android

how I can select (for example "pila 9v") and open a new screen?﻿
this is my code, but when I write for example "pila" it appears in the autocomplete list (pila 9v and pila 12v) and when I select "pila 12v", it takes me to the "pila 9v" activity, because that is the second one position in which that word is in the "string".

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] values = new String[]{"bateria 9v", "pila 9v", "bateria 12v", "pila 12v"};
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,values);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMercancias);
        textView.setThreshold(3);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item: " + adapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (position==0) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
                }
                if (position==1) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, 1);
                }
                if (position==2){
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main4Activity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,2);
                }
                if (position==3){
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Main5Activity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent,3);
                }



            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced same issue while working with AutoCompleteTextView and solved it this way.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
    //This will give you the string value of selected list item
    TextView listItem = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(0);
    //You can do this or apply own logic to find the selected value case
    Switch(listItem.getText().toString()) {
      case "bateria 9v": 
         Intent myintent0 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
         startActivityForResult(myintent0, 0);
         break;
      case "pila 9v":
         Intent myintent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
         startActivityForResult(myintent1, 1);
         break;
         //...

    }
    //or if condition
    if(listItem.getText().toString().equals(values[0]) {
      Intent myintent0 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
      startActivityForResult(myintent0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll see what I get.

Comment: Excuse me, in the section "case values [0] and the others ,says a message comes:

constant epression required

Comment: check the updated answer. Problem is that switch is not allowing to set any random value inside values array, it needs a constant.